# Can I sign a system app with platform key and my own key?

Tags: android, android-source

As I would like the system app to have system permission while also being able to use the other key/certificate to verify another user app. (The client app will connect to the system app via AIDL, which the system app will verify by signature as both apps are signed with one keystore).

This worked until when I was required to compile the app along with the Android AOSP. The app is then signed with the system key and the client can no longer verify.

From what I understand in the android.mk file, there is a line to indicate what to sign the APK with - LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := <name of APK>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <Name of APK>.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

So is it possible to indicate multiple certificates?
Like this - LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform, my_key

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear why your system app needs to be signed with the key as the client app. You can still have the system app verify the signature of the client app even if they are signed with different keys. Simply hardcode the certificate or public key you sign your client app with into the system app.

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, wouldn't hardcoding the certificate or public key be bad? That was why I thought we should only use the signature signed for verification

Comment: Hardcoding the cert in you system app code is no different from loading the cert from the system app APK.